# How to append functions to class functions

Tags: perl

I am writing a web API that has several functions, for example: login, logout, summary and so on.

Everytime I call any of those functions I check I convert the posted data to JSON and I check if the passport is expired

How can I pre append a function that does those two things every time I call a function of the api object

Comment: That heavily depends on the framework you are using. What are you using? Mojolicious, Catalyst, Dancer, CGI or something else?

Comment: `pre append` => `prepend`

Comment: Oh if @7stud's comment is what you are looking for, I [wrote a module](https://github.com/P-Seebauer/acme_autowrap/blob/master/lib/ACME/Autowrap.pm) for that once, but haven't put it on cpan yet, because of some bugs. You're better of with something from cpan, I think.

Comment: I'm using Mojolicious

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [**Sub::Prepend**](http://search.cpan.org/~lodin/Sub-Prepend-0.01/lib/Sub/Prepend.pm) may help you.

Sample:

```
use Sub::Prepend 'prepend';

    sub foo ($) {
        print "Foo executed with \@_ = (@_).\n";
    }

    BEGIN {
        prepend foo => sub {
            # This is called before foo executes.
            print "Foo was called with \@_ = (@_).\n";
            push @_, 'and more';
        }
    }

    my @bar = qw/ foo bar baz /;
    foo(@bar); # The prototype is preserved!

    __END__
    Foo was called with @_ = (3).
    Foo executed with @_ = (3 and more).
```